# jQuery, Javascript : Javascript wrapped in jQuery(), $() - what does it mean?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble understanding a type of jQuery selection, and I hope someone can explain it to me in clear terms.

It's taken from [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193425/how-do-you-animate-fb-canvas-scrollto).

Basically, it has the common jQuery: `$( selector )`.

But inside that it has `$({ y: iFrameScrollY })`.

I've never seen this before. **What does it mean to have `{ ... }` and `someVal: anotherVal` inside the brackets?**

*Also, please recommend a different title for this question, to make it easier for others to find it.*

Comment: That would be jQuery selector wrapped with object. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Regarding the `{}` syntax, that's a JavaScript object literal (also called an object initialiser). For more info read [Working With Objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects) or some other JS tutorial about objects. If you haven't seen it before then chances are it won't (yet) make sense to you when I say that according to [the `$()` function documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/), when you pass an object to `$()` it returns that object wrapped in a jQuery object.

Comment: Thanks Dr Dan and nnnnnn, that's really helpful. I'll read up on those docs.

Comment: @nnnnnn: +1 on your comment, very nice explanation and nice article on working with objects you linked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What `$({ y: iFrameScrollY })` does is wrap a jQuery selector object around the JavaScript object `{ y: iFrameScrollY }`.

The JavaScript object is declared `{ y: iFrameScrollY }`, meaning it contains a property named `y` set to the value of `iFrameScrollY`.

By wrapping the object into a jQuery object one can avail of executing jQuery methods against the wrapped object.

See this [**documentation**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) for more details.

Answer (score 3):

Wrapping plain JavaScript object inside jQuery object you can use few jQuery methods including: .data(),.prop(),.bind(), .unbind(), .trigger() and .triggerHandler().

Here is an example taken from jQuery.com:

```
// define a plain object
var foo = {foo:'bar', hello:'world'};

// wrap this with jQuery
var $foo = $(foo);

// test accessing property values
var test1 = $foo.prop('foo'); // bar

// test setting property values
$foo.prop('foo', 'foobar');
var test2 = $foo.prop('foo'); // foobar

// test using .data() as summarized above
$foo.data('keyName', 'someValue');
console.log($foo); // will now contain a jQuery{randomNumber} property

// test binding an event name and triggering
$foo.bind('eventName', function (){
        console.log('eventName was called');
});

$foo.trigger('eventName'); // logs 'eventName was called'
```

Answer (score 1):

That's a call to the [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery1) function, which is overloaded to do a lot of different things, depending on the arguments being passed.

The `{someVal : anotherVal}` is a JavaScript object with a property named `someVal` with a value equal to the value of the `anotherVal` variable.

If you join those two pieces of information together, and look at the linked page, you'll see this:

> jQuery( object )
>
> object A plain object to wrap in a jQuery object.