# Scrolling in Facebook canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, canvas

So I had this app on facebook and from the FB documentation I found that in order to trigger a scrolling functionality on click I first need to load the FB SDK by adding this code:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'i put my app id here',
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v2.3'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

and then I had this **img** with id #button1 that behaves like a button using jQuery click() method. I wanted to have the canvas scrolled to this element #button1 so I put this line of code into the click() method like this

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
   FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, offset);
}
```

Nothing happened. So I searched around and found this topic
[How do you animate FB.Canvas.scrollTo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7193425/how-do-you-animate-fb-canvas-scrollto)

so I added the function

```
function scrollTo(y){
FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(pageInfo){
                        $({y: pageInfo.scrollTop}).animate(
                            {y: y},
                            {duration: 1000, step: function(offset){
                                FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, offset);
                            }
                        });
                });
            }
```

and used it as

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
       scrollTo("#button1");
    }
```

nothing happens still. What happened ?

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter of the scrollTo function is the y value to scoll to.

In the first code, you did not defined the "offset" variable. You should see an error about that i your browser console.

In the second code (the custom scrollTo function with animation), you try to use a string (#button1), but it should be an y value (a number).

Try this for testing, it should scroll 100 pixels:

```
$("#button1").click(function(){
   FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 100);
}
```

Comment: i just did as you said, tried the simplest scroll as `FB.Canvas.scrollTo(0, 1000);` but didnt work either. could it be there was something wrong with my initiation of the sdk ? i checked fb documentation and it says the scrollTo must be used "in conjunction" with FB.Canvas.setSize() and FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow(). But I think in my app I only used FB.Canvas.setSize() so could that be the blocker? [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.Canvas.scrollTo)

Comment: I want add another thing is that the app is a JSP page with a flash game container, loading a **top.html** and a **bottom.html** files. the **img** button is an element of the **bottom.html** file. so I am not sure if an element within a child html file of the jsp could make the whole page scroll, whether this could be the problem

Comment: and i highly suggest not using iframes in your page, that makes everything a lot more complicated.

Comment: i am inheriting the structure from 2 generations of developers so it is not up to me whether or not to use iframe. I also tried to use navigate around the page using hashtag link but even that doesnt work. :(